# Android Touch delegate only triggers on right bottom only

Tags: java, android, android-touch-event

I am trying increase the touch area of an icon in my app without increasing the size. I am using touch delegate to achieve this. But the problem is that, the touch area is increasing only on the right-bottom, even though I have given left and top. Only right-bottom touch area increased. When I tap on right-top it won't get activated.

Is there anything else that need to specified to make it work properly?

```
findViewById(R.id.theme_parent).post(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        Rect delegateArea = new Rect();
        darkTheme.setEnabled(true);
        darkTheme.getHitRect(delegateArea);
        delegateArea.right += convertDpToPixel(18);
        delegateArea.left += convertDpToPixel(8);
        delegateArea.top += convertDpToPixel(18);
        delegateArea.bottom += convertDpToPixel(18);
        TouchDelegate touchDelegate = new TouchDelegate(delegateArea, darkTheme);
        if(View.class.isInstance(darkTheme.getParent()))
        {
            ((View) darkTheme.getParent()).setTouchDelegate(touchDelegate);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You want to _subtract_ from left and top.

Comment: Why is that so? Can you explain in details?

Comment: The `left`, `top`, `right`, and `bottom` fields in a `Rect` are basically the coordinates for each side in a coordinate system. To widen a rectangle to the left, you need to subtract from its left coordinate. Similarly so for the top, since zero is at the top. Does that make sense?